# Corrupted Robot Model in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

I'm trying to run multiple instances (18 instances) of gazebo in parallel processes on my system to do reinforcement learning. However i'm running into an issue where the robot model in some of the instances becomes corrupted, as in, the wheels becomes detached from the robot body for some of the gazebo instances.

With some trouble shooting, I think the problem might due to high CPU load, as I launch the gazebo simulations simultaneously. The problem seemed to be alleviated when i added some sleep time between launching each gazebo instance and reduced the number of instances. However, I don't know if this was the actual cause of my issue, and if there is a proper fix that I could apply to this.

Video 1: https://youtu.be/p5kU0BICVRI

Video 2: https://youtu.be/47Sd_2S1-Ls

[image: robot model breaking breaking]

[image: robot model breaking]

Comment: There's clearly something going wrong, but to be able to get a useful help you'll need to provide a way to reproduce the issue. Presumably there's something going wrong with the solver. But the source of the instability can't be isolated by just seeing the visual outputs. Please edit this to provide a minimal reproducible self contained example.

Comment: are you using sensors (they may run in other threads)? and which version of gazebo are you using?